# Passing values from GridView to code behind file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that binds values from the database.
Here is the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="DataView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField  DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Title" />
                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ProductId" DataImageUrlFormatString="getProductImage.ashx?ProductID={0}" HeaderText="Image">
                </asp:ImageField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDescription" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductCost" HeaderText="Cost" />
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Number" ID="txtQuantity"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:ButtonField Text="Button" CommandName="AddToCart" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I want to pass the command arguments containing values from txtQuantity and ProductID to the code behind on CommandName "AddToCart". 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Bind the values of the ProductID & Quantity in the GridView. In GridView, give like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="DataView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField  DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Title" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ProductId" DataImageUrlFormatString="getProductImage.ashx?ProductID={0}" HeaderText="Image">
            </asp:ImageField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDescription" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductCost" HeaderText="Cost" />
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Number" ID="txtQuantity" Text="<%# Bind("Quantity")%>"></asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:Button Text="Button" CommandName="AddToCart" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("Quantity") + "," + Eval("ProductID")%>"  />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

In GridView RowCommand event, give the below code:

```
  if(e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
  {
      string[] args = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(",");
      Decimal Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(args[0]);
      int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);          
  }
```

Comment: I tried that, but I am getting error as Literal content ('<asp:ButtonField Text="Button" CommandName="AddToCart" CommandArgument="') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.

Comment: Check whether u have given space between each properties inside the GridView?

Comment: Thevan, I added the button inside the item template.I think thats why he was getting ' Literal content ('<asp:ButtonField Text="Button" CommandName="AddToCart" CommandArgument="') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'

Comment: I do not think asp:ButtonField has got CommandArgument Attribute whereas asp:Button has it.